# Datebase efficiency

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two ways in which I could set up my database and I can see benefits in both, but I'm not sure what way is considered "the right way". It concerns a thumbs up system, as in Youtube style just to make it clear, for my website.

First idea for table layout (basic example)

```
USER = user_id, etc<br>
PROJECT = project_id, user_id, etc<br>
PROJECTLIKE = project_like_id, project_id, user_id etc<br>
PROJECTDISLIKE = project_dislike_id, project_id, user_id etc
```

Second idea for table layout (basic example)

```
USER = user_id, etc,<br>
PROJECT = project_id, user_id, etc<br>
PROJECTLIKEDISLIKE = project_dislikelike_id, project__id, user_id, like (boolean), etc
```

I feel the first one would be more efficient, but the second would be easier to write code for. Is there a better way or is it just preference.

regards

Comment: A database should be designed based on how the data is going to be used.  Your question doesn't indicate usage patterns.

Comment: I see your point, thanks for the reply

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design rather than coding .. with insufficient information to even give a design recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're unlikely to like and dislike something at the same time, a single table for "project affinity" might do the job.

This also has the advantage of having more options: "Like", "Dislike" or even "Meh" can be included easily.

It's inconvenient to have multiple join tables between the same two entities unless each join table stores different types of information.

Comment: thanks for your reply, great example thats swayed me to one table. Thoug would the two table soluton be more future proof in terms of normalization for database alterations down the line (if that makes sense.

Comment: The two table solution would be more trouble to maintain and less future proof. It also means querying two different tables to find out what someone's opinion on something was, which can enormously complicate any `JOIN` operations you might have. This is a violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). There is no two.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want

```
CREATE TABLE vote_types (
    vote_type INT,
    vote_type_desc VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE project_votes (
    project_id BIGINT,
    user_id BIGINT,
    vote INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id, user_id)
);

CREATE INDEX project_votes_aggregated (project_id, vote);

SELECT vote, count(*) FROM project_votes WHERE project_id = ? GROUP BY vote;
```

That index will slow down insertions a bit, but make that `SELECT` very fast. How you index things is actually the key to efficiency, here. The schema is more of a normalization problem.

Comment: More of a conecpt question than any code needed, but thanks for your reply